# Alignment issue in the Activity tab in Firefox browser

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, firefox

There is an alignment issue in the **Activity** tab. TThis bottom border is missing for the tabs, which has numbers in it. in the Firefox browser.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Bottom border]

After inspect the element, looks like `bounty-indicator-tab` class `vertical-align: middle` caused the issue.

**Configurations:**

- OS Version: Windows 10 Pro
- Firefox version: 54.0 (32-bit)
- Zoom level: 100%

Comment: Are you running any custom scripts?

Comment: @Burgi No, not any custom scripts.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Firefox 55.0.3 on Win 10... Try updating Firefox?

Comment: It appears fine for me, in all current versions of every browser, (Edge, FireFox, Chrome, IE11Win10).

Comment: @Mokubai I have updated Firefox _(current Firefox version is `56.0b3 (32-bit)`)_, still I can see the same issue.